# Get Data From A Foreign Key Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am trying to get all products related to an orderitem but am having a problem doing the query.
I want to list all products in an orderitem. Hope i have provided everything needed.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)

class Product(models.Model):
   category = models.ForeignKey(Category,related_name='products',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,related_name='items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='order_items',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Get list of product ids of a particular order
product_ids = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order).values_list('product', flat=True)
# Get products from list of product ids
products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)
```

Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: This one helped me solve the problem I had. I had to twist it a bit like this.                                        
    order = get_object_or_404(OrderItem,id=id,slug=slug)
    # Get list of product ids of a particular order
    product_ids = OrderItem.objects.filter(order=order.id).values_list('product', flat=True)
    # Get products from list of product ids
    products = Product.objects.filter(id__in=product_ids)

Answer (score 0):

an idea to do thas

```
# For all_entries
all_entries = OrderItem.objects.all() #or all_entries = OrderItem.filter(order = order)

# one orderItem 

for oi in orderItem:
  products_of_one_oi = oi.product
    for product in products_of_one_oi:
      print(product)
```

Comment: Hi Ulric Denis, I have tried your answer but I am getting an error that product is not itterrable since I am trying to get all products in an orderitem.